# Java - Eclipse Compiler Compliance Level 1.6 not working as expected

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, combobox

We're working on a project that still needs to run on a Java 6 environment, so I set in - Preferences - Java - Compiler - the Compliance Level and Source compatibility to 1.6. I expected to get compiler errors on stuff introduced in Java 7 or later.

While this is working for new features like the `try-with-ressource` statement, I don't get even a warning when using generics that were introduced after Java 6 like `ComboBox<..>` or `JList<..>`. In fact I get a warning when using raw types, even on `ComboBox` which wasn't generic in Java 6.

Two question:

- Why do I get errors using `try-with-ressource`, but not when trying to use `ComboBox<..>`?
- Is there some other options to toggle in order to see non-available generics as errors?

Note: I'm using IBM Rational Application Developer 8.5.5 which is built on Eclipse 3.6.3 (Helios) with a JDK 7 - not my choice, just what's given here ... deployment for the Java 6 environment is done elsewhere, I just have to guarantee that I'm not using Java 7 features, but the above doesn't seem to work as expected ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compliance level only covers language features such as try-with-resources.

The use of generics by a particular class is determined by the JRE/JDK library you are using. You will need to use an actual Java 6 JRE/JDK to get the correct checks. This also covers things like additional methods and classes introduced by later releases.

You can define additional JRE/JDKs in the Preferences in the 'Java > Installed JREs' page.

In the Properties for your project you can define the JRE/JDK to use in the 'Java Build Path' page.